# How do I pass html to a template dialog component using Material with Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to pass custom html from a specific page to a template component for dialog created using Material (MdDialog). Untill now I can pass simple data to the template like so:

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Input, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { MdDialog, MdDialogConfig, MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
    import { DialogComponent } from './dialog.component';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-commoncontent',
      template: '
       <div class="row  pull-right">
         <button md-raised-button (click)="open()" >{{"addButton" | translate}}
         </button>
       </div>',
      styleUrls: ['./commoncontent.component.css']
    })
    export class CommoncontentComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor(public dialog : MdDialog) { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

      open() {
          let config = new MdDialogConfig()
          let dialogRef:MdDialogRef<DialogComponent> = 
          this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, config);
          dialogRef.componentInstance.content = "Hello Angular"

      }
    }

    import { Component, OnInit, Input, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material'
    import { CommoncontentComponent } from './commoncontent.component'

    @Component({
       selector: 'dialog-common',
       template: '
         <md-dialog-content class="accent-color">
             <form class="form-horizontal" name="dialogForm">
                {{content}} 
             </form>
         </md-dialog-content>',
       styleUrls: ['./dialog.component.css']
    })
    export class DialogComponent {
      //@Input() templateDialog: TemplateRef<any>
      content:string;
      constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogComponent>) {}
    }
```

but I am unable to pass html. I know I can use ng-content for that but I couldn't manage to make it work.

Comment: Use `<span [innerHtml]=""` for inner HTML. However, make sure you pass it through `DomSanitizer` or else it will output an error. I suggest you implement a pipe for this.

Answer (score 18):

## Updates

### Update #1

The below code blocks are now updated to the latest version of `@angular/material`.

There is also a new example on how to pass custom HTML and it now shows how to pass the data to the dialog.

### Update #2

`DomSanitizer#sanitize` should be used instead of `DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustHtml`. (Thanks @binarylobster!)

---

## Method 1 (`Pipe`)

To pass custom HTML, simply add an `[innerHtml]="htmlContent"` attribute with `htmlContent` as the sanitized version of HTML (in this case, a `@Pipe()`) to the selector (such as `span`):

`my-dialog.component.html`:

```html
<h3 matDialogTitle>My Dialog</h3>
<mat-dialog-content>
  <div [innerHtml]="htmlContent | safeHtml"></div>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button matDialogClose>Close Dialog</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

`my-dialog.component.ts`:

```ts
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
// Other imports here

@Component({
  selector: 'my-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'my-dialog.component.html'
})
export class MyDialog {
  htmlContent: string;
}
```

`safehtml.pipe.ts`:

```ts
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private dom: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(value) {
    // NOTE: Consider using DomSanitizer#sanitize instead of DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustHtml, which executes code in `<script>` tags
    return this.dom.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, value);
  }
}
```

`app.component.ts` (Or wherever you would like to place the function):

```ts
import { MyDialog } from './my-dialog/my-dialog.component';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog){}
  htmlContent: string = '<p>Content goes here</p>';
  openDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyDialog);
    dialogRef.componentInstance.htmlContent = this.htmlContent;
  }
}
```

Afterwards, declare the pipe in your module file:

```ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // Other declarations here
    SafeHtmlPipe
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

---

## Method 2 (`DomSanitizer`)

UPDATE: Another way to sanitize the HTML is as follows:

`my-dialog.component.html`:

```html
<h3 matDialogTitle>My Dialog</h3>
<mat-dialog-content>
  <div [innerHtml]="htmlContent"></div>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button matDialogClose>Close Dialog</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

`my-dialog.component.ts`:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-dialog',
  templateUrl: './my-dialog.component.html'
})
export class MyDialog {
  htmlContent: string;
}
```

`app.component.ts`:

```ts
import { MyDialog } from './my-dialog/my-dialog.component';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';

// ...
export class AppComponent {
  htmlContent: string = '<p>Content goes here</p>';
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog, private dom: DomSanitizer){}

  openDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyDialog);
    dialogRef.componentInstance.htmlContent = this.dom.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, this.htmlContent);
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz demo (showcases both examples)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dialog-with-html-content-so)

Comment: You should only use `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` if you really really need <script> content to be evaluated. If you're just trying to pass simple html like formatting, modify the above examples to use `this.dom.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, this.htmlContent)`.

Comment: Also, `sanitize` returns a string, so there should be no reason to declare `htmlContent` in the dialog component as `SafeHtml`.

Comment: Hi @Edric
Thanks for above solution. 
However, what about passing complete html from component to dialog. 
example: <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="name" placeholder="name" maxlength="4" required>
  </mat-form-field>

In this case  it still works however material css didn't get apply.

Comment: @harsh You can try using a `DomPortalHost` or a portal from the Angular CDK.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @binarylobster! I didn't know that there was a `sanitize` method. Although the description for the `DomSanitizer` API does show: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#sanitize